# Dismiss and Present same view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

i have a view controller and i need to dismiss it and present it back in same time.
i had tried dismiss it and call back the view controller but not working.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
UIStoryboard *storyboard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ExpandViewController *expandView=
    [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ExpandViewController"];
expandView.delegate=self;
[expandView setEventDict:dict];
[self presentViewController:expandView animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: Please learn Markdown formatting so that others don't have to format your question for you.

Comment: __[OFF]__ but you just did it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what outcome/functionality you are looking for in your question, but @matt is correct. However, you may be looking to have this happen seamlessly. Therefore you could use child view controllers instead of presenting the view controller using the `[self presentViewController:VC animated:animate completion:nil]` method.

Adding child vc:

```
[self addChildViewController:myVC];
[self.view addSubview:myVC.view];
[myVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Removing child vc:

```
[myVC willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
... remove subview.
```

You can set up a delegate between the two controllers to tell the parent when to dismiss the view to make things easy. You can also add the subviews at different indexes using `[self.view insertSubview:myVC atIndex:index]` or the other possible functions such as the insert above subview etc, to have one subview be added before dismissing the other to give a more seamless transition.

Hope this helps!

Comment: actually what i want is currently i'm present a expand view controller but when a user click on the button in the view it will dismiss the expand view controller and present it back with another data.

Answer (score 1):

You can't present a view controller until the currently presented view controller has finished being dismissed. You won't know this has happened until the `completion` handler from your dismissal is called. Your mistake is that the `completion` handler is `nil`. Instead, provide a `completion` handler (in your first line), consisting of the remaining lines of your code. Thus, they will execute *after* the dismissal finishes.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    // ... the rest of your code goes in here ...
}];
```

Comment: is not working on this code. it direct dismiss the expand view as well

Comment: Show me your rewrite in accordance with the instruction in my answer. It sounds like you didn't do what I said to do.

Comment: [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
   UIStoryboard *storyboard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ExpandViewController *expandView=
    [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ExpandViewController"];
expandView.delegate=self;
[expandView setEventDict:dict];
[self presentViewController:expandView animated:YES completion:NULL];
}];

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm suggesting. I guess I don't understand what you're after, sorry. That code should dismiss the existing view controller and present a new one.